# Input text Box Validation inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

Am having a `ng-repeat` function wherein am displaying 3 input text boxes.But the sane button dosen't seem to apply validations(I need to enable 'Save' button only if I fill all the three inputs)

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text" ng-model=item.name required class="form-control">
    </div>
</form>
<button type="button"  ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.items=[{
                id:1,
                name:VALUE1
              },{
                id:2,
                name:VALUE2
              },{
                id:3,
                name:VALUE3
            }]
```

Comment: show us your complete form code.

Comment: Seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11317/

Comment: inputs are already filled  by item.name

Comment: I need for both the cases with and without input

Comment: your code is fine if there is no value in item.name Save is disabled http://jsfiddle.net/k7ecrbvu/

Comment: Thanks@squiroid Can you please add it as an answer

Comment: what if I have a time picker instead of a input text box.Does the answer remains the same ? http://jsfiddle.net/k7ecrbvu/2/

Comment: Have Just specified the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems working fine.Just need to know that if your model is empty then it will disable the button :-

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text" ng-model=item.name required class="form-control">
    </div>
</form>
<button type="button"  ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items=[{
                id:1,
                name:"VALUE1"
              },{
                id:2,
                name:"VALUE2"
              },{
                id:3,
                name:""
            }]

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7ecrbvu/)